# Why can't I build and run my Unity project through Xcode?

Tags: xcode, unity-game-engine

In Unity, whenever I go to File>Build & Run, the project fails to launch and I receive this message in the Console. This message shows even the project is blank. How can I fix this?

UnityException: Launching iOS project via Xcode failed. Check editor log for details.
UnityEditor.iOS.PostProcessiPhonePlayer.LaunchInXcode (BuildTarget target, System.String path) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/PlatformDependent/iPhonePlayer/Extensions/Common/BuildPostProcessor.cs:1720)
UnityEditor.iOS.PostProcessiPhonePlayer.Launch (BuildTarget target, System.String path) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/PlatformDependent/iPhonePlayer/Extensions/Common/BuildPostProcessor.cs:1693)
UnityEditor.iOS.iOSBuildPostprocessor.LaunchPlayer (BuildLaunchPlayerArgs args) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/PlatformDependent/iPhonePlayer/Extensions/Common/ExtensionModule.cs:22)
UnityEditor.PostprocessBuildPlayer.Launch (BuildTarget target, System.String path, System.String productName, BuildOptions options) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/PostprocessBuildPlayer.cs:282)
UnityEditor.HostView:OnGUI()

Comment: What unity version? What xcode version?

Comment: My Unity is version 5.3.3f1 and my Xcode is version 7.1.1

Comment: Are you building your Xcode project on Windows to later copy it on OS X? If that is the case, Unity cannot post-process the project properly. You would need to be on OS X to create the Xcode project.

Comment: No. I build and run it on OS X.

Comment: Sometimes, Unity does is lacking behind supporting xcode. Try this plugin from this page http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/unityexception-launching-ios-project-via-xcode-failed-check-editor-log-for-details.309642/#post-2257303. If that doesn't work for you, downgrade xcode to 6.3.2 and wait until unity releases Unity 5.4 this week. They may add fix the error in the 5.4 release.

Comment: which scripting backend are you using?

Comment: I use the standard MonoDevelop for scripting.